Deploy MultiPage VUE Application to Github
I've had a go at deploying a single page application to github (as annoying as it was having to follow different tutorials) but now I'm wanting to push a multipage vue website - that is, a website built with vue that has different pages rather than everything loading on one page - but I'm struggling to make it work.
I noticed that when I created the project, there was no vue.config.js file so I copied over the config file from my single page vue app (which has the github repository I'm trying to push to) but the github page turns to white when I do this. I think there was also an instance where the background colour of the website was the right colour but none of the components appeared.
If someone could explain how you build and push a vue multi-page app to github, that'd be much appreciated 
My VUE Multipage Directory
The vue.config.js file I tried adding to it from my single page projectThe errors in the web console when I push the final build to github pages

"I noticed that when I created the project, there was no vue.config.js file so I copied over the config", it doesn't seem like you should just do that.  Should find the reason why a Vue project was created without a Vue config file, it could mean other problems exist.  What steps did you take to create the project?  Also what about this app makes it "multipage"?  The directory screenshot doesn't really explain. Is it true MPA (more than one HTML file), or do you mean you have vue-router with multiple views (which is still SPA)?

Yes I mean vue-router with multiple views. I assumed MPA was the correct term since that was what I saw people use online. Apologies if that meant something else.
Whenever I try pushing the website I use the npm run build comment first and then put the new files in the dist folder into the github repo that runs the github page.

publicPath value should just be '/LL-PVP-GUIDE/' instead of full URL.  But also, github pages doesn't seem to support SPA routing (link).  You may want to look into an alternative host.  I know Netlify for example can handle SPA routing by simply adding a _redirects file to the project root folder.

sucks to hear, at least I now know for sure. Thank you for the help
